# Scribble: how to center a tabular?

Tags: latex, racket, scribble

I'm writing a technical paper with Scribble. The paper contains a table. I'm making the table with [`tabular`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._tabular%29%29). So far so good.

I want to center the table, but wrapping my [`tabular`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._tabular%29%29) with [`centered`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._centered%29%29) has no effect. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your table in a `centered` and also supply `'block` as a style argument:

```
#lang scribble/acmart
@title{Centered Table Below}

@centered[
  @tabular[
    #:sep (hspace 2)
    #:style 'block
    '(("hello" "world"))]]
```

Why?

- By default, a `tabular` makes a table that can contain page breaks
- The `'block` style prevents page breaks ([documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._table%29%29))
- And un-breakable tables happen to be implemented with a LaTeX macro that can be centered